# Different Ways to Load selected files in R

Tags: r

In a directory with 100 files (001.csv, 002.csv, ..., 100.csv), I want to load a range of selected files, e.g., file 30 to 50 (030.csv, 031.csv, ..., 050.csv).

One way is:

```
allFiles = list.files(directory)
csvFiles <- file.path(directory, allFiles[30:50])      
dataFrames <- lapply(csvFiles, read.csv)
```

This method seemed to work. But I still have question:

```
class(allFiles)
[1] "character"
```

allFiles is a character of length 100. **How to know the file names will be sorted in ascending order, so that 030.csv is in 30th, 050.csv is in 50th position, not any others?**

*Any other methods to read a selected range of files in R?*

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be using the Cousera webpage for assistance with your homework?

Comment: `list.files()` returns an alphabetized list, although I'm not sure that also means ordered numerically as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is just to use sort: `allFiles <- sort(allFiles)`.

But in general, I would recommend listing the files explicitly. You can do this as follows:

```
useFiles <- paste0(sprintf("%03d",30:50),".csv")
csvFiles <- file.path(directory, useFiles)
```

This way if someone adds another file to the directory later, your code is robust.

Comment: That makes a lot of senses!